# Icons not working in "Add New Post" page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I try to add a new post, Icons on the page are not displayed. I'm facing issues due to non-visibility of the icon and having difficulties while adding a new post. how to rectify this issue?

I have disabled all the plugins and still, the issue persists.

**strong text**[image: Screeshot of WordPress Admin Area]

Comment: check your browser's console log.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me.
I checked the console log and it shows 2 identical errors. I have attached the screenshot in the Link

https://i.imgur.com/JHdrGVl.png

Comment: It just a warning ignore it for now, which theme you use ? have you tried with disabling all the plugin for while.

Comment: I'm using Genesis theme and once I had disabled all the plugin and switched the theme back to default Twenty Nineteen but still the issue persists.

Comment: Does it also happen in a different browser?

Comment: Yes, It's happening in all browser